# Does anyone use the private IOTA network in their organisation?

Tags: iota-network

I am withdrawing this question as it is not specific as per rules.

<strike>I seeking to set up a private iota testnet https://github.com/schierlm/private-iota-testnet starting with a single-node for a Proof of Concept project. Please can you tell me of your experiences, especially challenges faced, in using it.</strike>